# how to get number according to maximum in java?

Tags: java

```
class racing_info{
    ArrayList<horse_info> list = new ArrayList<horse_info>();

    void racing_information() {
        System.out.println("====경주 정보====");

        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            int speedA = (int)(Math.random()*40)+30;
            int skillA = (int)(Math.random()*50)+20;
            int betA = (int)(Math.random()*9)+5;
            horse_info HI = new horse_info(speedA, skillA, betA);
            list.add(HI);
            System.out.println((i+1) +"번마 || 마속:" + HI.returnSpeed() + "  기수의 노련함:" + HI.returnSkill() + "  배당률:" + HI.returnBet());

        }System.out.println();

    }


    void winner_information() {
        double winner = 0.0;
        double max = 0.0;

        System.out.println("====승자====");
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            horse_info temp = list.get(i);
            winner = (temp.returnSpeed() * 0.3) + (temp.returnSkill() * 0.2);
            max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
        if(winner > max) {
            max = winner;

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
class horse_info{
    int speed = 0;
    int skill = 0;
    int bet = 0;

    horse_info(int a, int b, int c){
        speed = a;
        skill = b;
        bet = c;
    }
    int returnSpeed() {return speed;}
    int returnSkill() {return skill;}
    int returnBet() {return bet;}
}
```

I made a simple 'horse racing' code. So I was trying to get the winning horse by using 'if(winner > max){....' code. As result, I got the horse that has the highest point(= 'double winner' part) but I couldn't get which horse it is
simply, I want to get the result like this

```
System.out.println("No." + (i+1) + " horse is the winner!!!");
```

Comment: why don't you just put your if winner > max inside the for loop?

Comment: I cringe when I see lower cased first character and underscore in class names

Comment: With your current code, the last horse will always be the winner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain your winner, you can change your `winner` to an int representing winner's index:

```
void winner_information() {
    int winner=0;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        horse_info temp = list.get(i);
        if(calculateProficiency(temp) > calculateProficiency(list.get(winner))
            winner = i
    }
    //Print your winner horse (i) info
}
double calculateProficiency(horse_info h) {
    return (h.returnSpeed() * 0.3) + (h.returnSkill() * 0.2);
}
```

This code, if there are more than one horse with the same "proficiency" (and they are winners), **will print only first of them**.  As an exercise, you should seek how to show all of them.